# Spring boot running from Eclipse vs running from Terminal [Not Loading properties file]

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, properties, terminal

I am working on spring boot application in which I have made a property file,

> application.properties

```
#Generated by Eclipse Messages Editor (Eclipse Babel)
# ===============================
# = Spring Application
# ===============================

server.port = 80
```

and here is main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder().sources(SpringBootWebApplication.class).properties(System.getProperties()).run(args);
}
```

it is working fine when I am running it on eclipse.

if when I am running using commandline:

```
java -jar target\tmfboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

application is running on default port of tomcat **8080**

I think it is not loading `application.properties` file while running using terminal.

I’m using Maven 3.2.

Comment: what is the reason that you are doing this `.properties(System.getProperties()`?

Comment: you just need `SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);` in `main ` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `properties` file should be under the `resources` folder.
if you using maven/gradle it should be under `src/main/java/resources/application.properties`

Answer (score 0):

change your `main` method as follows, it will load the `application.properties` from `src/main/resources` folder

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```